# Nested query in INTERVAL

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.2

So I am trying to have a select statement within an INTERVAL in postgres

```
UPDATE v_obligation 
    SET current_alert_level=0,
        last_update_date=now()AT TIME ZONE 'PST',
        next_due_date = (now()+INTERVAL ''(
                 SELECT recurrence FROM v_obligation 
                         WHERE obligation_id=4) Day'')
    WHERE obligation_id = 4
```

But I am getting a syntax error in the nested query. I can't recall doing anything like this before. As you can see I tried escaping the quotes, but to no avail.

Sincere thanks for any help... It is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a simple way to convert integer to interval, eg.

```
select now()+ (select 5) * '1 day'::interval
```

So try this:

```
UPDATE v_obligation 
    SET current_alert_level=0,
        last_update_date=now()AT TIME ZONE 'PST',
        next_due_date = (now()+
                (SELECT recurrence FROM v_obligation 
                    WHERE obligation_id=4)* '1 day'::interval
    WHERE obligation_id = 4
```